# Redirect certain filetypes to another folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is this,

right now I have to link to /theme/css/somecssfile.css,

what I want to be able to do is this

/css/somecssfile.css, but still keep the physical file in /theme/.

This is my current .htaccess

```
# Enable Rewriting  
RewriteEngine on  
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|files\/images|files\/css|files\/js|files\/swf|files\/upload)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.css)$ /theme/$1 [L,NC]
```

If you want to include `.js` also in this rule then use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(?:css|js))$ /theme/$1 [L,NC]
```